# Parar Fila Dinâmica C++ com valor negativo

Tags: c++

Preciso parar de enfileirar quando o usuário digitar um numero negativo (-1) e imprimir todos os valores digitados, como faço isso?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Define a Estrutura Nó
struct No {
    int valor;      // Valor armazenado
    No * prox;      // Ponteiro para próximo elemento da lista
};

// Define a Fila
struct Fila {
    No * ini;       // Início da fila
    No * fim;       // Fim da fila
};

// Insere valor da lista
int inserir(Fila &f, int valor);
// Remove elemento da lista
int remover(Fila &f, int &valor);

int main(void) {
    // Declara e inicializa fila
    Fila fila;
    fila.ini = fila.fim = NULL;

   // Variável para armazenar dado digitado
    int dado;
    int n;

    while (n>0) {
        cout << "Digite um numero inteiro: ";
        cin >> dado;
        inserir(fila, dado);
        n--;
    }

    // Agora mostra o reultado...
    while (remover(fila, dado) == 0) {
        cout << dado << endl;
    };
}

// Insere um valor na fila
int inserir(Fila &f, int valor) {
    No * tmp; // Ponteiro para armazenar endereço de nó temporariamente
    // Cria nó
    tmp = new No;
    // Configura nó...
    tmp->valor = valor; // Valor do nó
    tmp->prox = NULL; // Sempre insere no fim da fila
    // Se lista vazia, insere primeiro elemento
    if (f.ini == NULL) {
        f.ini = f.fim = tmp; // O primeiro elemento é o primeiro e o último
    }
    // Se lista não está vazia, atualiza lista...
    else {
        f.fim->prox = tmp; // Pendura novo elemento no antigo fim
        f.fim = tmp; // Indica que novo elemento é o novo fim
    }
    // Retorna que inserção ocorreu com sucesso
    return 0;
}


// Remove um valor da fila
int remover(Fila &f, int &valor) {
    No * tmp; // Ponteiro temporário
    // Se a lista está vazia, vai embora
    if (f.ini == NULL) return 1;
    // Armazena valor do elemento sendo removido
    valor = f.ini->valor;
    // Armazena endereço de elemento a ser removido
    tmp = f.ini;
    // Aponta inicio da lista para segundo elemento (novo primeiro!)
    f.ini = f.ini->prox;
    // Remove o primeiro elemento da lista
    delete tmp;
    // Boa prática... se a lista ficou vazia, atualiza último ponteiro
    if (f.ini == NULL) f.fim = NULL;
    // Retorna novo início da lista
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @bigown é o mesmo código sim, ainda estou trabalhando nele, como voc^sugeriu, Eu tirei o contador/limitador de iterações.

Comment: Edite lá ao invés de abrir outra pergunta. Porque a pergunta é a mesma e só mudou um detalhe e ainda ninguém respondeu. De qualquer forma veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Para saber quando parar não precisa ser uma fila, basta ser uma série de dados quaisquer, onde esses dados vão não importa. O problema que você está pergunta não tem nada a ver com fila dinâmica.